# Significance of hidden fields $$viewid, $$xspsubmitid, $$xspexecid, $$xspsubmitvalue and $$xspsubmitscroll

Tags: xpages

When I view the source of my XPage I see the some hidden fields `$$viewid`, `$$xspsubmitid`, `$$xspexecid`, `$$xspsubmitvalue` and `$$xspsubmitscroll`. There are some articles like [this](http://xpagesblog.com/XPagesHome.nsf/Entry.xsp?documentId=88065536729EA065852578CB0066ADEC) and [this](http://dontpanic82.blogspot.com/2010/03/xpages-making-validation-behave.html) which explain that `$$xspsubmitid` contains the ID of the event handler that triggered the update. Not much information seems to be available for other fields.

What is the significance of these fields?

Comment: $$viewid contains the ID for the backend control tree associated with that XPage. You need that if you are accessing the backend controls.

Comment: $$xspsubmitscroll is used to pass the location on the page the submit button is to the server, so that it knows to scroll back to that position when returning.

Comment: @SimonO'Doherty: I think you should put these in answer rather in comments :)

Comment: It seemed incomplete and not a full answer. If I find the other two I'll do it. ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok the details I could find.

**$$viewid** = Contains the ID for the backend control tree associated with that XPage. You need that if you are accessing the backend controls. Detailed in the "XPages Portable Command Guide".

**$$xspsubmitid** = Is loaded with the Event handler ID of what event you want to execute.

**$$xspsubmitvalue** = The value you are submitting.

**$$xspexecid** = The execution ID of controls you want validators to run on (as far as I know).

**$$xspsubmitscroll** = This is used to pass the location on the page the submit button is to the server, so that it knows to scroll back to that position when returning.

They are mostly used by XSP.fireEvent() (Used Internally by XSP.attachEvent(). Private function). If you want to see the DOJO code related to these, it is contained in the **XSPClientDojo.uncompressed.js** file.

Another place to read up on these is here:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.ui.doc/wpd_controls_events.html