# Can I see from CSJS if an Xpage have been submitted?

Tags: javascript, xpages

Is there any way to find out in CSJS if my XPage has already been submitted or not?

$$xspsubmitid I can not use on csjs, but are there alternatives?

Comment: By "submitted", do you mean a partial refresh has been triggered or do you mean the traditional web page "submitted", i.e. full page submission including processing of the form / saving of the document? `$$xspsubmitid` probably wouldn't be of relevance - it's a hidden field populated during a partial refresh to pass back to the server which component triggered the partial refresh https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14380359/significance-of-hidden-fields-viewid-xspsubmitid-xspexecid-xspsubmitv/14382957

Answer (score 4):

You can use the XPages client side library XSP to do a `XSP._isDirty()` check to see if changes have been made to the page since the last submission. This does require that you set enableModifiedFlag to true on your XPage.